# Add revision diffs to API?

Tags: feature-request, api

This may be a bit of a stretch, but I was wondering if it could be possible for the API to return the diff between two revisions? Or the next best option, to have the API return the markdown value of each answer you request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually *is* possible to get the markdown of an answer using the following URL:

> http:// **{site}** /revisions/ **{revision GUID}** /view-source

*Note: you may need to scrub some HTML out of the resulting page you get.*

Comment: For some reason, I didn't think to go beyond the API. Thanks for connecting the dots for me. :)